# CrudRepository inside my custom repository implementation

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

I am attempting to get a reference to my repository interface (`UserRepository`) that extends `CrudRepository` within my custom implementation (`UserRepositoryExtensionImpl`) in order to gain access to all the methods provided by Spring JPA.

Crud Extension:

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, String>, UserRepositoryExtension<RosterUser> {
    ...any custom spring JPA methods...
}
```

Extension Interface:

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepositoryExtension <T> {
   public T put(T entity);
}
```

Custom Implementation:

```
public class UserRepositoryExtensionImpl implements UserRepositoryExtension<User> {

    UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    public UserRepositoryExtensionImpl(UserRepository userRepository) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public User put(User user) {
        System.out.println(user + "was put");
        // ...put logic here
        return null;
    }...
}
```

However, I am unable to inject `UserRepository` since a circular dependency exists (given that `UserRepository` extends the interface implemented by my `UserRepositoryImpl`). I am getting the following error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name '    userRepositoryImpl': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular     reference?
```

A possible, but less than ideal solution would be to inject and `EntityManager` into `UserRepositoryImp`, but in that case, I do not have access to any of the Spring JPA methods provided by `CrudRepository`, or any additional methods that I might have created in UserRepository.

Any suggestions on how to get around this?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: As mentioned in @shelley's answer, I was able to solve this by making 3 changes:

- Removing the `@Repository` from `UserRepositoryExtensionImpl`
- Renaming `UserRepositoryExtensionImpl` to `UserRepositoryImpl`. Apparently this makes Spring aware of the implementation's existence. See [Spring Doc](http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/repositories.html#repositories.custom-implementations)
- Removing my constructor and moving the `@Autowired` to the `userRepository` field

SUCCESS!

Comment: If there isn't any actual circular dependency (ie: Spring just get confused because it thinks you have many beans of similar type). Add additional qualifier such as bean id so Spring knows which bean to autowire.

Comment: give us your spring app context

Comment: @gerrytan - I could be wrong, but I do think there is a circular dependency. FYI: The same problem is being referenced [here](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?132889-Spring-Data-Calling-default-CRUD-methods-inside-a-custom-repository-implementation&p=439701#post439701)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A couple small things need to be changed in order for this to work:

- Remove the `@Repository` annotation from the custom repository interface (`UserRepositoryExtension`).
- The custom repository implementation should actually be named "`<StandardRepository>Impl`" rather than "`<CustomRepository>Impl`". In your code example, this should be `UserRepositoryImpl` instead of `UserRepositoryExtensionImpl`.

Comment: Thanks @shelley! Your suggestion, in addition to moving the `@Autowired` from the constructor to `userRepository` field solved the problem. I can now reference the `UserRepository` within my custom implementation. :)

Answer (score 4):

As shelley pointed out, the naming is really important to make the autowire work. In the example below, I follow the right naming standard for my custom interface and its implementation. But my interface that extended the JpaRepository was named “ItemDao” instead of “ItemRepository”, this resulted in that spring ignored my custom implementation altogether...

OBS!!! Should be "ItemRepository"

```
@Repository
public interface ItemDao extends JpaRepository<Item, Long>, ItemRepositoryCustom {}
```

my interface

```
interface ItemRepositoryCustom {...}
```

my implementation class

```
class ItemRepositoryImpl implements ItemRepositoryCustom {...}
```

If anyone have similar problems, start by following the naming standard that is used in the spring documentation at the link below.

http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.custom-implementations

Comment: I wish that details such as these were mentioned more explicitly... But yea, naming appears to be pretty important. Glad you were able to figure it out too!

Comment: Me to, when you read a section of the documentation without prior spring knowledge, there is no way to figure out how strict the naming rule is.

Comment: It doesn't work in spring boot 3.0.8

Answer (score 1):

Well in this case I suggest to use the `@Lazy` annotation.

```
public class MyCustomRepositoryImpl implements MyCustomRepository {

    @Lazy
    @Autowired
    private MyRepository myRepository;

    @Override
    public boolean customMethod() {
       return myRepository.count() > 0;
    }

}
```

With constructor parameter Spring tries to create the "basic" repository class which require you custom repository which requires you "basic" repository - the typical case with circular dependency.

Without `@Lazy` but with only the `@Autowired` it also won't work (there will be problem with factory bean for the basic repo).

I think in this case the `@Lazy` is the most elegant solution.

Comment: Hero of my day! Pozdravujem do Polska!

Answer (score 0):

There is a [well defined way to create custom repository implementations in Spring Data JPA](http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/repositories.html#repositories.custom-implementations) which you should follow. Basically you need to extend `CrudRepository` so you don't have to inject an instance of it in your custom implementation.

Comment: I think OP is following that approach but would like to use methods from the standard repository bean within the custom repository implementation.

Comment: @zagyi, Shelley is correct. I am trying to follow the very same approach Spring suggests, and this is how I found myself in the position I am in. I will add more details to the question in order to make the issue more clear.

Comment: @shelley, @Julian: sorry, after carefully re-reading the question, it's clear that I badly misunderstood it. However I think it's a weird thing what Julian tries to do. Usually it's a service class where you would inject repository instances and implement higher level methods that call one or more repository operations. Check wheter it would make more sense to move the logic of `put()` one level higher into a service interface/class.

Comment: @zagyi - I see your point. Since it is a PUT (an actual HTTP method), I felt the repo would be most appropriate place for this logic. Additionally, if I was to do this, this class would be a wrapper for my repository (correct me if I'm wrong) hence I would have to write wrappers for all the spring-provided methods (which would not be ideal IMHO). But that would be a possible solution. I actually got it to work by following shelley's suggestion and one more subtlety.

Comment: If that `put()` is really a HTTP request handler, then I think you should under no circumstances put it in the repository. According to the standard layering of a Spring webapp, it belongs to the _second_ layer above the repository (controller->service->repository).

Answer (score 0):

I have solved problem by injecting `ApplicationContext` and getting bean in lazy way using `applicationContext.getBean(UserRepository.class)`.
It works this way.

Answer (score 0):

I found I way of how to do it without the need for `@Autowire`:

```
public interface UserRepository extends 
    UserRepositoryBasic,
    UserRepositoryExtension 
{ 
}

public interface UserRepositoryBasic extends
    JpaRepository<User, String>
{
    // standard Spring Data methods, like findByLogin
}

public interface UserRepositoryExtension 
{
    public void customMethod();
}

public class UserRepositoryExtensionImpl implements
    UserRepositoryExtension 
{
    private final UserRepositoryBasic userRepositoryBasic;

    // constructor-based injection
    public UserRepositoryExtensionImpl(
        UserRepositoryBasic userRepositoryBasic)
    {
        this.userRepositoryBasic = userRepositoryBasic;
    }

    public void customMethod() 
    {
        // we can call all basic Spring Data methods using
        // userRepositoryBasic
    }
}
```