# Adding behaviour to single repositories which uses base repository methods

Tags: spring, design-patterns, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I want to add custom behavior to single repository as described in [1.4.1 Adding behaviour to single repositories](http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/data-jpa/docs/current/reference/html/repositories.html#repositories.single-repository-behaviour). In this custom behavior I want to use method already present in my base repository (like `save()` or `findOne()` method). Ho can I achieve this in Spring data?

I tried extending my `UserRepositoryImpl` with `SimpleJpaRepository` to have basic `SimpleJpaRepository` methods available. But this way I got instantiation problems.

Also using aproach described in [1.4.2 Adding custom behaviour to all repositories](http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/data-jpa/docs/current/reference/html/repositories.html#repositories.custom-behaviour-for-all-repositories) doesn't seem like good solution, because it's way too much code for adding one simple method. In this case Spring Data seems more like burden.

Or is it antipatern to add to my repository such simple method which depends on other methods from base repository? Should I rather move this method to service/business layer?

Answer (score 1):

The same question came up a few days ago [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15124937/1276804). As I wrote there as well, I strongly believe this is an antipattern, so my answer to your last question would be a definite yes.