# Spring 4 autowiring fails in JPA-Entity/domain class

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, autowired

[I pushed a reproduction of the problem, in a much simpler form, onto a GitHub repository for you to see.](https://github.com/SakeSushiBig/spring4AutowireEntityDomainObjectProblem)

I'm encountering a problem with springs dependency injection on a domain class, which is also annotated as `@Entity` and used with spring-jpa/hibernate.

Basically I try to access a repository within the class for validation. I put the `@Configurable`annotation on the class, made sure `spring-aspects` was loaded by gradle, and setup the unit test to use my application configurations. The repository itself is annotated with `@Autowired` and `@Transient`. But still, the repository won't be injected (is null). In the test class I wrote, the repository was autowired with not much effort. What am I missing here? I already browsed through nearly every article/forum entry/stackoverflow question which seemed at least slightly releated to my situation. But all the suggestion, which eventually helped were already implemented by me.

Comment: Depending on the container setting up loadtime weaving is more difficult. Have you setup the agent (which is now called spring-instrument not spring-aspect btw) to enable loadtimeweaving (if needed on your platform).

Comment: Have you tried not autowiring, i.e. instantiating a PersonRepository implementation yourself ? I don't see how Spring is supposed to know which object to instantiate.

Comment: Also, have you seen this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15124937/crudrepository-inside-my-custom-repository-implementation ? You haven't used the `@Repository` annotation, which seems to be key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good catch to @blagae.

1.)
But looking at the code, it shouldn't be checking unique name like that. Should annotate the entity correctly to create a unique constraint or a unique index etc.

2.)
In the test case, the Person obj is created by a new operation, so no injection. It needs to be retrieved thru an instance of ApplicationContext. And Person itself needs to be marked as @Component.

3.)
The Person's hashcode() is throwing exception on a post destroy method after passing the test. I don't quite understand this one yet but basically you need to check for name==null.

4.) 
name is missing @Column annotation.